# Why does CHKDSK find file system errors after formatting a disk?

Tags: windows, ntfs, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption

I'm having trouble copy data to a brand new disk. I don't know yet if this is the result of the tools I've used, sequence of events during copying, or some issue with the files prior to being copied. I thought that a fresh format prior to copying was sufficient to reset the file system but now I'm not so sure.

The disk I'm copying from is a hardware RAID10 with a failed disk. I ejected the wrong disk while trying to pull the bad one and it had to resynchronize. I can only assume that the disk is working properly as I haven't had any issues with it. But I want it backed up before I try to insert a replacement.

I initially performed the copy operation using Cygwin and `rsync` but this method had [issues with symbolic links](https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin/2021-January/247233.html).

I then tried using `xcopy` which had [problems of its own](https://superuser.com/questions/1614655/).

As a third option I decided to try using `robocopy` which seemed to work fine but eventually started running into its own set of errors where it couldn't read a directory **on the disk being copied onto** (everything is fine on the disk being copied from):

```
The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

Between each of my failed copy attempts I perform a quick format on the disk. This time I did a quick format and then a `CHKDSK` which returned file system errors.

Setting aside the problems I have experienced while trying to backup my files, I have now performed a lot of operations on this brand new disk. But a quick format should erase all of this an leave me with a brand new file system.

Why then does CHKDSK find *file system* errors when scanning after having just formatted the disk?

The file system on both disks (copying from/to) are NTFS and I am using Windows 10 x64.

CHKDSK log:

```
C:\chkdsk r: /F /R

The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Backup (2021/1/2).

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  256 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 1.96 milliseconds.
  0 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.62 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.34 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  1 reparse records processed.
  278 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 15.39 milliseconds.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 0.37 milliseconds.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 0.79 milliseconds.
  1 reparse records processed.
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 0.85 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 4.78 milliseconds.
  11 data files processed.
 Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 0.96 milliseconds.

Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
  240 files processed.
File data verification completed.
 Phase duration (User file recovery): 175.03 milliseconds.

Stage 5: Looking for bad, free clusters ...
  488333817 free clusters processed.
Free space verification is complete.
 Phase duration (Free space recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.
Adding 82 bad clusters to the Bad Clusters File.
Correcting errors in the master file table's (MFT) BITMAP attribute.

Windows has made corrections to the file system.
No further action is required.

1953497087 KB total disk space.
     35924 KB in 8 files.
        72 KB in 13 indexes.
       328 KB in bad sectors.
    125819 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
1953334944 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 488374271 total allocation units on disk.
 488333736 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 206.34 milliseconds (206 ms).
```

**UPDATE:**

The last copy attempt failed with a new error:

```
2021/01/04 06:51:46 ERROR 4392 (0x00001128) Accessing Destination Directory 
The data present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.
```

I'm going to try another disk.

Comment: It might be best to replace the disk.

Comment: I'm not confident that it's a problem with the disk. It's brand new.

Comment: Some disks fail immediately. I suggest to use the warranty and not to try to fix a bad disk.

Comment: On brand new HDDs the defect rate is relative high. See image 2 "Lifecycle failure pattern for hard drives" on page 8 of the following paper: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bianca/papers/fast07.pdf It is sometimes called the "lifecycle bathtub" because of it's appearance.

Comment: Try using 2 different HDD an see what results you get, I know it's expensive to do it this way but at least you know.

Comment: I have a second disk I'm planning to try (also brand new) but I'm waiting on this last copy attempt after running CHKDSK.

Comment: Is this by any chance a relatively cheap 1TB+ external drive?

Comment: @gronostaj They are both "Certified Repaired" Seagate 2TB ST2000DM001. So much for certified or repaired.